# Having issues building a simple JavaScript Quiz

Tags: javascript

guys!

I am trying to build a basic quiz application using JavaScript and I came across a little "bump"

Why doesn't my code store an element of the allQuestions array in the currentQuestion variable ?

This is the code:

```
var allQuestions = [
            {question: 'What is the first letter of the alphabet?',
             choices: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
             correctAnswer: 0
            },
            {
             question: 'What is the second letter of the alphabet?',
             choices: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
             correctAnswer: 1    
            },
            {
             question: 'What is the third letter of the alphabet?',
             choices: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
             correctAnswer: 2    
            },
            {
             question: 'What is the last letter of the alphabet?',
             choices: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'z'],
             correctAnswer: 3    
            }];

var currentQuestion = {};

function pickRandomQuestion(arr) {
    return this[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length)];
}

currentQuestion = pickRandomQuestion(allQuestions);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are querying `this`, which would be the parent context - presumably a `window` since I can't see a parent `function`. You need to look up against `arr` instead:

```
function pickRandomQuestion(arr) {
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you call `pickRandomQuestion` and not `something.pickRandomQuestion`, the value of `this` inside it is `window`.

Replace `this` with `allQuestions`

Comment: Since I am passing the arr argument to the function, doesn't [this] refer to [arr] ?

Comment: @shinpou No, `this` always refers to the context, that's why parameters need to be declared in the first place

Comment: @shinpou — No, that would be `arr` or `arguments[0]`